# How can I get sensor data into Unity while using Google Cardboard?

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-cardboard

I have the basic Google Cardboard Unity application loaded and working great.

I want to utilize a few sensors on my phone that aren't available in Unity.  For example, I want to get access to the STEP_DETECTOR sensor.

I created my own UnityPlayerActivity, and without Cardboard, it seems to work well.  My problem is that I have no idea how to use my custom UnityPlayerActivity WITH cardboard.

From what I can tell, the cardboard demo uses a "UnityCardboardActivity" class as the main activity.  I took a look at UnityCardboardActivity.jar and it looks like the UnityCardboardActivity class inherits from CardboardActivity, NOT UnityActivity.

So my guess is that UnityCardboardActivity is manually starting the default UnityPlayerActivity somewhere in its code, but I can't change that to start my own custom UnityPlayerActivity in any way that I can tell.

Is there any way to get that sensor data without using a UnityPlayerActivity?

I tried making my activity extend UnityCardboardActivity instead, but for some reason I don't have access to the "getSystemService" method when do that, so I can't get access to any sensors.

Comment: Could you post some code? Besides, one solution would be to use a native dll that exposes access to all the sensors you would like to have and use it with Unity using the CardboardSDK Unity package provided by Google. Unity 5 Personal allows this and is free (this wasnt possible with Unity free for 4.X and older)

Comment: The thing is, I can see that "UnityCardboardActivity" just extends "CardboardActivity", which is a Google class and not a Unity one.  The AndoridManifest.xml only shows the Cardboard Activity listed as the main activity, so the "UnityCardboardActivity" must be starting the UnityPlayerActivity from within its code, and I don't see a way of modifying it to use my activity instead, since I think it's hard-coded.  

I'm trying to avoid doing things with the NDK and Unity since my time is limited, so I am probably just going to implement my own step detector.

Comment: UnityCardboardActivity doesn't actually start a UnityPlayerActivity, it replaces it and just makes similar calls.  (The source of UnityPlayerActivity.java is available in a Unity installation directory.)  I assume when you tried to inherit from UnityCardboardActivity you fixed the AndroidManifest to start your activity class instead?  Not sure why you couldn't call getSystemService, unless it's a permission issue.

Comment: Hmm, I just tried to copy and add the "UnityCardboardActivity.jar" file that  was in the Cardboard project and add it as a library to Android Studio, the same way I did with the UnityPlayerActivity.jar.  It let me create an inherited class from it, but like I said I couldn't access normal Android "Activity" class methods.  Do I need to import that file some way different?